# Write data to a temporary file with filename stored in an R environment

Tags: r, if-statement, temp

I have some data the I would like to write to a temporary CSV file in R.

Users have the option to specify a filename of their choice, which is stored in an environment (called 'envr') separate from .GlobalEnv

```
if (!is.null(envr$filename)) {
    write.csv(df, file = paste(envr$filename, ".csv", sep = ""))
  }
```

In order to do this successfully, I need to create a temporary file that is assigned to the filename chosen by the user.

```
if (!is.null(envr$filename)) {
    file.name <- get("filename", envir = envr)
    tempfile(fileext = ".csv")
    write.csv(df, file = file.name)
```

}

The above if statement however does not do the job, as a CSV file is not saved in $TMPDIR.

How can I easily integrate tempfile() into the first if statement above without having to assign it to a variable name (file.name)?

Comment: What do you mean by "*without having to assign it to a variable name*" ?

Comment: I've edited the code (second if statement) in my post. Hopefully it illustrates what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: So you want to create a *csv* file form the environment variable and store it in a temporary folder?

Comment: Yes, in a nutshell. I think using get() to extract the filename is the right idea...

Comment: Please have a look at my answer. Let me know if I didn't understand you well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may concatenate the file name (obtained from the `filename` environment variable) with the temporary folder of the session (using `tempdir()`), along with the `.csv` extension, as follows:

```
if (!is.null(envr$filename)) {
  write.csv(df, file = paste0(tempdir(), "/", get("filename", envir = envr), ".csv"))
}
```

Let me know if it answers your question or if you need any further help.

Comment: Glad I could help.